# How to show or convert (non-standard) \U0099 for Trademark "TM" Character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I've ran into some issue displaying the trademark "TM" character on my UILabel.
The "TM" character having problem showing up is \U0099 instead of the usual \U2122 
I dig a little deeper and find out the "TM" character \U0099 belongs to a very few Chinese fonts.

So I'm guessing iOS doesn't have the font to show it in labels or does not recognize it at all.

I've tried to scan my data for "\U0099" and stringreplace it to \U2122, but seems like NSString functions will escape unicode characters automatically so this "TM" character won't even be there.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or can give me suggestions as to how to deal with this \U0099 character?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `\U0099` isn't a valid Unicode character. Where is the `\U0099` coming from? Why isn't the proper character being used?

Comment: It's from the client's database. The client is based in Asia so I'm assuming they have many of their data in Chinese. [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/index.htm) I know for a fact you can have variations of a character  in other languages' input methods. For example "," and "，"

Comment: Unicode is Unicode regardless of language or locale. `\U2122` is the only Unicode character for the TM symbol. It may be that your client is using some non-Unicode (or non-UTF) character encoding that results in the TM symbol being encoded with a hex value of `99` but it wouldn't be `\U0099`. If you know what encoding the data is in, you can simply create an `NSString` from the `NSData` using the proper encoding.

Comment: I see. The funny thing is the entire data is in UTF8 and everything else is fine expect for this \U0099 character so I can't really convert the NSData in any other encoding. Thanks a lot rmaddy.

Comment: If they are using the wrong character then you need to convert instances of the `\U0099` character to `\U2122`. Show what you have tried so far to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me how you've obtained your `NSString` or what you have actually tried to solve your problem. So this suggestion might be completely unsuitable, but let's see if it helps...

U+0099 is an unassigned Unicode control character, it is not a TM symbol. It is fairly hard to get this character into an `NSString` as Clang at least objects if you place the escape into a literal, and Cocoa fails to translate a sequence of bytes in UTF-8 into an `NSString` if it contains it. This problem might be what is behind your comment that you could not string replace it.

*However* starting with UTF-16, I did manage to create a string with U+0099 in it:

```
unichar b[] = { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x99, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66 };
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:b length:14 encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

That is the string "abc\U0099def" (calling `characterAtIndex:3` will show you this).

Using the same approach an `NSString` with just U+0099 in it can be generated:

```
unichar notTMChar = 0x99;
NSString *notTMStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&notTMChar length:2 encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

and that can be used in a string replace call:

```
NSString *t = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:notTMStr withString:@"™"];
```

giving `t` the value "abc™def" as required.

**Warning: We are dealing with an unassigned Unicode control character here. Clang/Cocoa rejected it in UTF-8, it is probably unintentional that it accepted it in UTF-16. Using C library functions to do this is probably more reliable. Xcode 5.1.1 with Clang 5.1 was used for the tests.**

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
I've talked to my clients and they agreed that \u0099 shouldn't be there.
I have also implemented rmaddy's suggestion to replace instance \u0099 to \u2122.

```
    NSString *problemString = dictionaryWithU099AsValue.description;
    if ([problemString rangeOfString:@"0099"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *fixedDescriptionString = [[[problemString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U0099" withString:@"U2122"];

    // Then I reconstruct the NSString back to a new NSDictionary
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the trademark symbol ™ appears as hex 99 in [Code Page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (a common Windows character set).